# RxJS split observable sequence in multiple output

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Is it possible to split a single observable flux in multiple other observables?

My use case is a form that a user can submit. The submit action is handled in an observable, and on this action, there's a validator listening.

```
submitAction.forEach(validate)
```

The thing is I want to bind actions to either the `success` or the `failure` of the validator check.

```
validationFailure.forEach(outputErrors)
validationSuccess.forEach(goToPage)
```

I'm not sure how similar cases are handled in reactive programming - it may be that splitting the observable is just not the right solution for handling this kind of issue.

Anyway, how would you handle a similar case?

Answer (score 14):

Can you just use `map` and `filter`, possibly with `share` to avoid repeatedly executing the validation logic?

```
var submitAction = // some Rx.Observable
var validationResult = submitAction.map(validate).share();
var success = validationResult.filter(function (r) { return !!r; });
var failure = validationResult.filter(function (r) { return !r; });

success.subscribe(goToPage);
failure.subscribe(outputErrors);
```